# Barplot with ggplot: ordering variables and transparency for main categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a stacked bar-plot where the bars are ordered by decreasing value of a grouping category - bars with 100% of this category should go first - marked on the left image with an arrow- and where the main category (category with the highest %) is somehow highlighted, like on the right image.

I've tried several ways to reorder the original data frame and reorder the variables from `ggplot` without success. For the transparency, I've tried to use the argument `alpha` but I don't know how to ask to select only the most common category per bar.

From the sample data below, I would like to have ID on the X axis and Prop on the Y axis, while habitat would be the variable filling the bars. The firsts bars should be those with a 100% of any habitat category. For those with different habitat categories, the main one should be highlighted (or the others should be more transparent).

[image]

Sample data >>

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("ASA 1", "ASA 1","ASA 1","ASA 1","ASA 2","ASA 2","ASA 2","ASA 2","ASA 3", "ASA 3", "ASA 3","ASA 3", "ASA 4", "ASA 4","ASA 4","ASA 4"),
habitat = rep( c( "Cultivated", "Heathland", "Moss", "Vegetated"), 4) ,
prop = c(50, 20, 10, 20, 5, 80, 5, 10, 100, 0, 0, 0, 25, 30, 35, 10),
main = c("Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated",  "Heathland", "Heathland", "Heathland", "Heathland",  "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Moss", "Moss", "Moss", "Moss"))
```

Comment: can you add the code you used to generate the plots you tried?

Answer (score 1):

For the alpha thing, you've already have a `main` column in your data, you can just set `alpha = habitat == main`.

For the order thing, one option is to use ID as a factor with the levels in the appropriate order. Alternatively, you can set `scale_x_discrete(limits= lvls)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c("ASA 1", "ASA 1","ASA 1","ASA 1","ASA 2","ASA 2",
                        "ASA 2","ASA 2","ASA 3", "ASA 3", "ASA 3","ASA 3", 
                        "ASA 4", "ASA 4","ASA 4","ASA 4"),
                 habitat = rep( c( "Cultivated", "Heathland", "Moss", 
                                   "Vegetated"), 4) ,
                 prop = c(50, 20, 10, 20, 5, 80, 5, 10, 100, 0, 0, 0, 25, 30, 
                          35, 10),
                 main = c("Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated", 
                          "Cultivated",  "Heathland", "Heathland",
                          "Heathland", "Heathland",  "Cultivated", 
                          "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Cultivated", "Moss", 
                          "Moss", "Moss", "Moss"))

# Set levels in order of groupwise maximum proportion
lvls <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(prop == max(prop)) %>%
  arrange(-prop) %>%
  pull(ID)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(ID, lvls), prop, fill = habitat, alpha = habitat == main)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great! Thanks:)